# target="_top" emulation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frame, frames, frameset

Suppose we have frameset of with 2 frames, one frame is kind a tiny horizontal header and second is kind of "content" frame with 3rd-party html page inside. When user clicks on some link inside "content" frame, the whole page (frameset) should be reloaded with this link, the same behavior if "content" frame has "target=_top" attribute. How to do this using JS?

The main problem here is - that I can't edit html of "content" page.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `window.location` to the target URL.

Comment: I think you mean `window.top.location`

Comment: I believe it should be `window.top.open(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){
        // set target="_top" to reload whole frame
        var links = this.content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
            var link = links[i];
            link.target="_top";
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<frameset rows="50,*" frameborder="0" onload="load()">
   <frame src="/header.html" scrolling="no">
   <frame src="/content.html" name="content">
</frameset> 

</html>
```